# Not getting desired format from Oracle query

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to fetch data from data base in below format,

```
Month    Count
-----    -----
201208   124
201209   0
201210   56
201211   25
201212   0
201301   184
201302   0
```

In database I have entries like,

```
Month     Count
-----     -----
201206    56
201208    124
201210    56
201211    25
201301    184
201304    49
```

Below is my query,

```
SELECT MONTH, Count 
FROM   TABLE_NAME 
WHERE  MONTH BETWEEN 201208 AND 201302 
AND    ID = 'X'
```

Output :

```
Month     Count
-----     -----
201208    124
201210    56
201211    25
201301    184
```

Can anyone help me getting data in desired format.

Answer (score 1):

First you should generate full month's sequence between these dates. You can do it with [CONNECT BY LEVEL](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques) in Oracle. then just JOIN this sequence with your table:

```
SELECT MonthSeq.MONTH, 
       NVL(Count,0) Count
FROM   TABLE_NAME 
RIGHT JOIN
(
  SELECT
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201208','YYYYMM'),
                     (ROWNUM-1))
          ,'YYYYMM') MONTH
   FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL<=
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('201302','YYYYMM') ,
                      TO_DATE('201208','YYYYMM'))+1 
) MonthSeq 
    ON TABLE_NAME.MONTH=MonthSeq.MONTH 
ORDER BY MonthSeq.MONTH
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddb90/12)</kbd>

**UPD:**

Your query from the comment should looks like the following. You should move WHERE condition to the JOIN ON. If you use it in WHERE you don't get rows with zero counts.

```
SELECT MonthSeq.MONTH, 
       NVL(SUM(TOTAL_SESSIONS),0) AS SESSIONS
FROM   X
RIGHT JOIN
(
  SELECT
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201208','YYYYMM'),
                     (ROWNUM-1))
          ,'YYYYMM') MONTH
   FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY LEVEL<=
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('201302','YYYYMM') ,
                      TO_DATE('201208','YYYYMM'))+1 
) MonthSeq 
    ON X.MONTH=MonthSeq.MONTH and  X.acct_id = 'ABCD' 
ORDER BY MonthSeq.MONTH
```

Comment: Even that is not working                                          SELECT MonthSeq.MONTH, NVL(SUM(TOTAL_SESSIONS),0) AS SESSIONS 
FROM X
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201210','YYYYMM'),(ROWNUM-1)),'YYYYMM') MONTH
   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<= MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('201305','YYYYMM'), TO_DATE('201210','YYYYMM'))+1) MonthSeq
ON X.MONTH = MonthSeq.MONTH
WHERE
acct_id = 'ABCD' group by MonthSeq.month ORDER BY TO_DATE(MonthSeq.month, 'YYYYMM')

Comment: I've added a query for this case in the answer. And please if you want to get ANY help here or in another place then you MUST describe WHAT is not working (What error do you get?) not just "Even that is not working"...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TO_DATE` function to convert the month field to `DATE` format. Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) for more in detail. Try like this,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(MONTH, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYYMM') month, count
FROM   TABLE_NAME 
WHERE  month BETWEEN TO_DATE('201208', 'YYYYMM') AND TO_DATE('201302', 'YYYYMM') 
AND   id = 'X'
ORDER BY TO_DATE(month, 'YYYYMM');
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion. But this is also not working. If in database no entry for any month then i need count 0 for that month in output.

Comment: @user1607729, Okay, then you need do it with `CONNECT BY LEVEL` as suggested by @valex.